# Mongo/Mongoid erratic behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I have a very basic model - `User`

I am trying to do some basic CRUD operations on it. In rails console (rails c) I cannot do some of the basic persistence tasks. Like `User.delete_all` does not work. Or the following does not work either

```
u = User.first
u.name # prints "Shane"
u.name = "Pete"
u.save!
u.name # prints "Shane"
```

I am not sure whats going on here. My insert/new document operations do work fine.

Here's the versions info -

```
Mongoid - 2.4.7
Mongo db version v2.0.4
Rails - 3.2.2
```

User model -

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document    

  store_in :users, capped: true, max: 1000, size: (1000 * 1000)

  field :name, type: String
end
```

Comment: How does your User model look? Does saving work when using the [mongo shell](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Overview+-+The+MongoDB+Interactive+Shell)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define your User model like a capped collection. But in capped collection you can't do Update on document if the document change of size. In you case, your document change of size.

Avoid having a collection in capped and your update can work.